# Safe use of window.postMessage, is "if ( event.source !== window){return;}" alright?

Tags: javascript, security, message-queue, postmessage

I'd like to use `window.addEventListener("message",myOnmessageCallback,false)` for receiving messages only coming from my `window` itself. (this is to say I do not want to needlessly make the `myOnmessageCallback` function prone to be receiving malicious messages from some other sources (*I assume such might be other frames, browsersWindows, tabs, parent and iframes, right?*).

Therefore I thought, if this avoid touching anything from not my `window` itself.

```
function myOnmessageCallback(event)
{
  if(event.orign !== window)
  {
  // I assume the message is from not this window here, therefore ignore it.
  return;
  }

  //do some useful stuff with the message received (only from window)
}
```

Does this seem a good way to reduce the myOnmessageCallback callback for just dealing with
messages send via `window.postMessage()` of the webpage itself?

PS: For those who think why I desire such reduced `postMessage` `onmessage` capabilities. I want to have a way to put something in the Javascript execution Queue, allowing the handling of UI stuff in between. I would use the classical `window.setTimeout` but this has the minimum time and I do not want to needlessly waste time.

Comment: Is the HTML5 specified 4ms min time for `setTimeout()` actually going to be noticeable?

Comment: @jfriend00 yes, I fear it might be a problem because of the frequency. I want to be able to allow the script to be smooth (not blocking the UI etc.) so I have to defer, release the stuff the script does frequently back to the Javascript execution queue. I wished there was the `window.setImmediate()`.

Comment: The guys at [polyfill setImmediate.js](https://github.com/NobleJS/setImmediate/blob/master/setImmediate.js) seem to conclude that simply checking the window is not enough. They use some Math.random() UUID kind of once to make sure. This even more makes me wonder....

Comment: As I said in my other comment, the only way this additional UUID that `setImmediate.js` is using actually improves security is if you don't trust that the browser actually forces `event.source` to the window object of the sender.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`event.origin` is not a window object.  It's a URI.

`event.source` is the source window object.

It does appear that you can limit messages to be only from yourself if you check:

```
event.source === window
```

The MDN doc for postMessage states this:

> Any window may access this method on any other window, at any time,
>   regardless of the location of the document in the window, to send it a
>   message. Consequently, any event listener used to receive messages
>   must first check the identity of the sender of the message, using the
>   origin and possibly source properties. This cannot be understated:
>   Failure to check the origin and possibly source properties enables
>   cross-site scripting attacks.

I would interpret this to mean that you should also check to see that event.origin matches at least your domain and perhaps even that it matches your exact URL if you're only expecting to send messages to the same window.

You can check both origin and source with code like this:

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf(e.origin) === 0 && e.source === window) {
        // passed safety check, OK to process here
        console.log("passed");
    }
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/j3A8k/

---

I wonder if you're overcomplicating things here to try to save 4ms with `setTimeout()`.  From the MDN page for postMessage:

> If you do not expect to receive messages from other sites, do not add
>   any event listeners for message events. This is a completely foolproof
>   way to avoid security problems.

---

In your comments, you seem to indicate you're doing this a LOT and that's why you're worried about 4ms.  You haven't said anything about what your actual problem is that you're trying to solve, but you should be able to do a meaningful amount of work (e.g. several seconds worth of work), then yield with `setTimeout()` then do some more work.  Or, if you really want to do work in the background perhaps webWorkers are a better way to do this.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I also like your suggestion in the end. All things I have thought about. F****ng IE8 crap makes it hard to adopt Webworkers and there are still 10% (dec 2013) are not smart users and stick to IE8 (I cannot understand). So the better alternatives seem not to there (I actually wished I could use them:). For now I think I will just go with "good trust" in the suggested check.

Comment: @humanityANDpeace - I added a code example for how to check both `e.origin` and `e.source`.  Note that `e.origin` is only the domain of the source, not the full path.

Comment: Right! this should allow for another security test. I wonder still why the guys at [setImmediate.js](https://github.com/NobleJS/setImmediate) anyways implemented some "Math.random" nonce thing... It seems they actually care about performance. So if the solution conceived here is "bulletprof" I wonder why they do all this extra work, to make certain the message is not from elsewhere.

Comment: @humanityANDpeace - all that random nonce is doing is another check to see if the sender really was your window. Since global variables are stored as properties of the window object, checking to see if the passed nonce is the same as the one you have in your own window global variable is effectively the same thing as checking to see if the one sending the message actually was your window. The only way this adds any security is if you don't trust that the browser actually sets `event.source` to the sender of the message. Doesn't seem necessary to me.

Comment: maybe you are right! the "hack" to even use PostMessage with its powers and risk to something I actually would be happy to use avoid in the first place. Seems better to use `setTimeout(fn,0)` (actually meaning 0ms delay) or `setImmediate` as a clearer way. It has been discussed [here] (http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/07/09/the-case-for-setimmediate/). Well I assume that the trust that the browsers sets window correctly is something I can live with. I would not use the nonce as it costs time... Thanks for all help here!

Comment: @jfriend00 Why `window.location.href.indexOf(e.origin) === 0`, and not `e.origin === "https://" + window.document.domain` ?

Comment: @MikhailBatcer - You could probably use that.  Yours doesn't include a port number if there is one.  And, yours requires manually modifying the code for http or https whereas this answer uses whatever protocol the page is using.  Old answer, took me awhile to regain the context.